# xslt - Remove data in a foreach statement with particular text()

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML file and I apply an XSLT file to output a text file where each lines are defined per Records.

```
<Data>
    <Record>
            <Identification1>AA123</Identification1>
            <SomeNode1>...</SomeNode1>
            <SomeNode2>...</SomeNode2>
            <SomeNode3>...</SomeNode3>
            <SecondIdent>XX123</SecondIdent>
            <SomeNode4>...</SomeNode4>
    </Record>
    <Record>
            <Identification1>BB123</Identification1>
            <SomeNode1>...</SomeNode1>
            <SomeNode2>...</SomeNode2>
            <SomeNode3>...</SomeNode3>
            <SecondIdent>XX123</SecondIdent>
            <SomeNode4>...</SomeNode4>
    </Record>
    <Record>
            <Identification1>CC124</Identification1>
            <SomeNode1>...</SomeNode1>
            <SomeNode2>...</SomeNode2>
            <SomeNode3>...</SomeNode3>
            <SecondIdent>AA123</SecondIdent>
            <SomeNode4>...</SomeNode4>
    </Record>
    <Record>
            <Identification1>DD123</Identification1>
            <SomeNode1>...</SomeNode1>
            <SomeNode2>...</SomeNode2>
            <SomeNode3>...</SomeNode3>
            <SecondIdent>XX123</SecondIdent>
            <SomeNode4>...</SomeNode4>
    </Record>
    <Record>
            <Identification1>DD123</Identification1>
            <SomeNode1>...</SomeNode1>
            <SomeNode2>...</SomeNode2>
            <SomeNode3>...</SomeNode3>
            <SecondIdent>XX123</SecondIdent>
            <SomeNode4>...</SomeNode4>
    </Record>
</Data>
```

I've already created a code (below) that checks each Data/Record and test if another node (let's say SomeNode2) have more than 8 digits. This is working great.

The output was then :

```
AA123;...;...;...;XX123;...
BB123;...;...;...;XX123;...
CC123;...;...;...;AA123;...
DD123;...;...;...;XX123;...
XX123;...;...;...;XX123;...
```

Simple, easy, done.

However one asked to exclude all the Data/Record that have an *Identification1* in any of the *SecondIdent* of the file with the particularity that it should excluse only those who begins with "AA". This is the most difficut par to solve for me.

The output should looks like:

```
BB123;...;...;...;XX123;...
CC123;...;...;...;AA123;...
DC123;...;...;...;XX123;...
XX123;...;...;...;XX123;...
```

I'm not able to find an appropriate solution.

**EDIT : in this example as *Identification1* "AA123" is present in *SecondIdent*, it should be removed because it begins with 'AA'. However the *Identification1* "XX123" is present because it doesn't begin with "AA" even if it is present multiple times.**

I tried those solutions:

- xsl:key : somehow I can't get this working. It seems to be more a knowledge issue than a coding issue :)
- Try to create a variable "$count" that counts the number of times the Identification1 is present in SecondIden. Then in the if statemnt in the XLM below, I added with te variable "=0" (not working, empty document) and the count directly in the if statement

( count(/Data/Record/EFA_ISIN_IDENT[contains(., $ISIN)]) = 0

```
It worked but when I tried to make another condition based on "AA" then I ran into problems (data not displaying or he kicked out all Identification beginning with "AA").
```

xslt code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:variable name="separator" select="';'"/>

<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select="Data/Record">
        <xsl:if test="( (string-length(format-number(./SomeNode2/text(),'0;0'))&lt;= '8') )">       
            <!--1.Identification-->
            <xsl:value-of select="./Identification1/text()"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
            <!--2.SomeNode-->
            <xsl:value-of select="./SomeNode1/text()"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/>
            <!--3.SomeNode-->
            <xsl:value-of select="./SomeNode2/text()"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/> 
            <!--4.SecondIdent-->
            <xsl:value-of select="./SecondIdent/text()"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/> 
            <!--5.SomeNode-->
            <xsl:value-of select="./SomeNode2/text()"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="$separator"/> 
            <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;'" />
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Last but not least :  I apologise for my english and all typos/grammar and thank you for you help !

Comment: One typo is that you select `Data/Record` in your XSLT, but in your XML you have `Records`. Also, you refer to a `$delim` variable in your XSLT which you have not defined. You should really correct these. Thanks!

Comment: Corrected. I made typos when I narrowed the code for the example ! Once again, thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression you want is this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="Data/Record[not(Identification1 = ../Record/SecondIdent and starts-with(Identification1, 'AA'))]">
```

If you want to use a key (which might be better with a larger data set), define it like so (This must be a direct child of `xsl:stylesheet`)

```
<xsl:key name="secondIdents" match="Record" use="SecondIdent" />
```

And use it like so....

```
<xsl:for-each select="Data/Record[not(key('secondIdents', Identification1) and starts-with(Identification1, 'AA'))]">
```

Comment: Direct child of xsl:stylesheet ? That's where I did it wrong for the xsl:key part ! Thank you very much ! I'll test and give you feedback !

Comment: Hi Tim. I've tested, it is working for the for-each part but it doesn't work for the 2 first characters of the Second Ident. Added a clarification in bold for your convenience.

Comment: I've amended my answer to include logic for checking for "AA" too.

Comment: Boom you made my day, this is working just as expected ! Thank you !!